# Two identical wp-includes directories on server

Tags: directory, server

I've recently noticed that I have two identical directories in my WordPress main directory. It's the wp-includes directory. I checked it and this is what I got:

```
drwxr-xr-x 18 admin admin    12288 mar  7 10:27 wp-includes/
drwxr-xr-x 18 admin admin    12288 feb 21 23:01 wp-includes*/
```

As far as I know, one of them is an executable directory (!?). Should I delete one of them? Which one? Anyone knows why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an "executable directory". The `x` means something different for directories:

> The execute bit allows the affected user to enter the directory, and access files and directories inside
>
> [Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21252)

Also the `*` doesn't mean executable for directories hear as you might think if you've read [that answer](https://superuser.com/a/178808).

Instead it is just a directory with the name `wp-includes*`.

I'm not sure what has happened there but as the folder should be called `wp-includes` but the second one is called `wp-includes*` the second one is probably not used anyway.
How that happened? No idea.

Final note - if you remove that directory be careful. `*` is [a wildcard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) and is expanded by the shell. So you need to escape it.

So use something like `rmdir wp-includes\*/`.

Comment: I'd use FTP/SFTP to remove the 'asterisked' folder. I'd rename it to something else, then take a peek at the files therein to see if they are suspected malware.